# Using a webcam with Point Cloud Library (PCL)

Tags: cloud, point, point-cloud-library

Is it possible to use a webcam with Point Cloud Library (PCL) or do I need to use a depth-sensor camera?

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on what you want to do. There is some functionality in PCL for processing 2D images (point clouds with only x and y coordinates basically) - e.g. [edge detection](http://www.pointclouds.org/assets/cvpr2012/PCL_Enhancements.pdf) but I guess PCL is not the place you would first go for that functionality (see OpenCV).

If you want to make best use of PCL you need a 3D point cloud. To get there from webcams you need to use one of, in order of increasing difficulty:

- A multiple camera setup.
- Structure from motion.
- Depth from single images.

Comment: By the way, something I forgot to mention: a 2D point cloud might make sense if, for example, you are obtaining irregular data in two dimensions like what might happen with a mobile robot and a 2D laser scanning.